# listening in to keypresses and "click outside" for popovers/particular classes

Tags: javascript, popover

I am implementing popovers, since the existing libraries are not flexible enough. I want to set any div with a class `.popover` and it shows the behaviors:

1. destroy on escape key
2. destroy when clicks outside borders

Both are events, and both need to apply on elements classed as `.popover`. To destroy popovers on escape:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {

  if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
    popovers = $(".popover");
    //destroy popovers
 }
});
```

But I am stuck with how to listen in to mouse clicks **globally** and determining if they happened outside of a `.popover`.

SO [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/153047/604511) mention having a global click listener that destroys all `.popover`s and adding a click listener to **each** popover that halts event propagation to the global listener.

But I want to define it only once globally, not once for every single popover I make. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
  if(!$(e.target).hasClass("popover")) { 
       //if element does not have a ".popover" class => it's outside
   $(".popover").remove();
  }
});
```

where e.target is the  element you clicked on

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a div covering the whole page with z-index -1.
2. On popover you can bring it to front
3. Register popover closing onclick event on that div
4. On popover close, bring it back behind all elements.